# React setState is not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I read that setState is async but I don't see this is the case here because I can log "particip" on the console. All the other setStates are wokring. I don't understand why only setParticipants is not doing anything. At he beginning I though that because "particip" is an array of objects I'm doing something wrong. Later on I tried with simple letters and numbers just to see whether the state will be updated or not. Much to my surprise there was nothing happening and I frankly don't understand why.

```
const [participants, setParticipants] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  const socket = io(BASE_URL);
  setSocket(socket);
  socket.on("msgToClient", (msg) => {
    setChat((chat) => [...chat, { ...msg }]);
  });
  socket.on("joinedRoom", (particip) => {
    console.log(particip);
    setParticipants(particip);
    console.log(participants);
  });

  socket.on("leftRoom", (particip) => {
    console.log(particip);
    setParticipants(particip);

    console.log(participants);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Where is the `setState` call?

Comment: Yes, `setParticipants` is async so doing `setParticipants(particip)` and `console.log(participants)` immediately afterwards will show the old data always. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To guarantee that when I call setParticipants it will be executed and the state will be set, so I can use it. Although I don't understand how the other setChat is working and setting its state with no problems.